# Brightness control not available in ubuntu 14.04 acer veriton desktop

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I have just installed **ubuntu 14.04** on **acer veriton** desktop and can not reduce the screen brightness.

Below is a screen shot of the '**brightness and lock**' settings. Unfortunately it does not show any control for brightness.[image]
I have tried several things I gathered from similar questions on this forum, but none works.

1) Using the command `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5` gives the output :

```
`warning: output LVDS1 not found; ignoring`
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
```

2)  I tried creating a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20ntel.conf` with contents :

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

3) The folder `/sys/class/backlight/` does not have any contents

4) In `/etc/defaul/grub` I have the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Sadly it looks like I am very unfortunate, none of the above solutions is working. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

command is not perfectly written..
I was having same problem too.. and sufferd a lot 
 this  used to give me same error to  -   `xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5`
 bt after searching .. i found out `lvds1` is not the proper way to write
   right way is `LVDS-1` 
this name u can find by running `xrandr` without any parameters :
hense use  this

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness 0.5
```